# Error in file (con, "r"): cannot open with translateR

Tags: r, google-translate, translate

Im trying to translate a lot of text from Italian to English using translateR in R.  My file also contains other languages and I have successfully used translateR to translate these.  The Italian represents the biggest amount though with over 4000 rows of short text segments to translate. Any idea what the problem is, or if there is a problematic data entry how to find it?  I split the dataframe into half and the second half of the df appeared to run okay for a longer time than the original df but then the error message appeared again.

The error message is

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

which doesnt tell me much.  A traceback() gave the following:

16: file(con, "r")

15: readLines(content)

14: paste(readLines(content), collapse = "\n")

13: withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) 
invokeRestart("muffleWarning"))

12: suppressWarnings(paste(readLines(content), collapse = "\n"))

11: structure(x, class = unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x))))

10: I(suppressWarnings(paste(readLines(content), collapse = "\n")))

9: fromJSON(getURL(api.url))

8: fromJSON(getURL(api.url))

7: googleTranslate(x, google.api.key, source.lang, target.lang)

6: FUN(X[[i]], ...)

5: lapply(X, FUN, ...)

4: mclapply(to.translate, function(x) googleTranslate(x, google.api.key, 
       source.lang, target.lang))

3: unlist(mclapply(to.translate, function(x) googleTranslate(x, 
       google.api.key, source.lang, target.lang)))

2: unname(unlist(mclapply(to.translate, function(x) googleTranslate(x, 
       google.api.key, source.lang, target.lang))))

1: translate(content.vec = magg.it.2$text, google.api.key = "foo", 
       source.lang = "it", target.lang = "en")

Comment: It means that it cannot read the file: check that you specified correctly the file name and path.

Comment: actually, splitting the df even smaller seems to be working for some of the subsets.  I think it must be some limit with the google API.